# JSON Data Assigning to Javascript Var Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, chart.js

Im retrieving JSON Data and assigning those into Javascript and display Chart (im using Chart.js).

`[{"name":"yasiru","col1":"300","col2":"50","col3":"100","col4":"40","col5":"120"}]`

```
 var pieData = [
        {
          value: obj[0].col1,
          color:"#F7464A",
          highlight: "#FF5A5E",
          label: obj[0].name
        },
        {
          value: 50,
          color: "#46BFBD",
          highlight: "#5AD3D1",
          label: "Green"
        },
        {
          value: 100,
          color: "#FDB45C",
          highlight: "#FFC870",
          label: "Yellow"
        }
      ];
```

when i run this. `label : obj[0].name` correctly show the `Yasiru` name without any problem. but Value is not. 
so i tried just `alert(obj[0].col1);`
then it shows 300 as i needed. am i doing something wrong?

Here PHP code im using. FYI

```
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $response = array('name' => $row['username'],
    'col1' => $row['first'],
    'col2' => $row['second'],
    'col3' => $row['third'],
    'col4' => $row['fourth'],
    'col5' => $row['five']
);

    $responses[]=$response;
```

Comment: Are you trying to get "value" or "Value"? They are going to be different properties.

Comment: This works fine for me. Are you sure you're using `pieData[0].value`, not `pieData[0].Value`? The capitalization matters.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ i dont know how to remove it. im retrieving it from PHP server side. ill add that code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj[0].col1` is a string, try checking the docs to see if chart values can be defined as strings, or only numbers. In this case, it seems like it might only accept numbers.

In the meantime, using `parseInt` should work fine:

```
value: parseInt(obj[0].col1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because your values are strings and Chart.js expects only integers. Try the following JSON code instead:

```
[{"name":"yasiru", "col1": 300, "col2": 50, "col3": 100, "col4": 40,"col5": 120}]
```

By the way, prefer using the console when debugging, instead of `alert()`: `console.log()`

Comment: How to remove "" when i retrieve the Data from PHP? please check my PHP Code